# ASP.NET Core dynamic ports for Pub/Sub

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am creating pub sub for ASP.NET Core API and multiple ASP.NET Core MVC Clients.
So I would have some API Calculation who would send changed data to API Pub/Sub Service and him to send to subscribed MVC Clients.
My problem is that in mine MVC Client app in `launchSettings.json` there is set port

> "iisSettings": {
> "windowsAuthentication": false,
> "anonymousAuthentication": true,
> "iisExpress": {
> "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:50187",
> "sslPort": 44366
> }

Currently this is the why I am connecting to my MVC Client from ASP Pub/Sub service

```cs
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
string baseUrl = Configuration.GetValue<string>("AppSettings:BaseUrl");
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
var contentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(contentType);

HttpResponseMessage response = await 
client.GetAsync(employeesApiUrl + "/Create?model=" + "Ok");
```

So this is my first time programing in ASP.NET Core and I wonder is my approach good and how can I make dynamic port so every new client have its own unique port?

Comment: the port is to the client not for the client.... aka think of server.... server has an ip if you dnt use that server ip, what are you connecting to... same story here..... if the connection port is 2632... and you dont use this... then what are you connecting two. pub is pubish... as server, and sub is subscription aka a client..., this is more used in a subscrition type setup like rabbitMQ, or the likes which this is not..., so you are mixing terminology in the wrong context, above is just server/client.. and changing ports or ip to server without setting it up so, it just wont work

Comment: U are right I was having wrong view on things. So if I want to have pub/sub when my client subscribe its enough to save his username (because is unique)?

Comment: if you are confused with terms, then you should avoid using them, as you just confusing ppl trying to help. Above you have code which creates a httpclient, baseUrl, is where the api you are calling exists. that itself is a web server... of sorts. I think plan down what you are wanting and avoid words/terms you don't know the meaning of and then maybe we can help.

Comment: Let me try saying it like this. I have two users logged in. And on view of user1 there is some count 20 and on view of user2 there is count 50. Now in some process on server count from 20 go to 25. How do I change that in a view on user1 without user1 clicking on anything.

Comment: from what you describe. it sound like you need to look into `signalr` .net core